# How to get latest code from original branch to your already existing branch in git

Tags: git, github

I am working on the branch `xyz` which was originally taken from branch `develop`.
After committing the files and pushing it for review it was pointed that another change happened in the original `develop` branch which is required for the changes in the new branch `xyz`. This change is in file `F`

I want to put the latest changes in file `F` (origin) to the new branch `xyz` without having to commit changes in git. But I am suspecting that if I take the latest file, it will remark that I have changed it in `xyz`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid making a commit? If you made changes to a branch that you want to share, it is usual to commit (and maybe push). But you could stash your local changes, make a merge (merge changes from another branch in yours) and then apply the stashes changes to your branch on top of the merged result.

Comment: See [Git-Branching-Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing). Its helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jverhoelen, @pRaNaY.
This works.

Steps:

1. Pull latest code and switch to the working branch -> there will be conflicts
2. Perform a git merge with origin branch to resolve conflicts
3. Use a git merge tool - i used p4merge and it was really good
4. the conflicts will be highlighted/bordered with >>>>... <<<<... symbols
5. one has to remove these conflicts by deleting manually either the part of origin or one's own changes along with the extra >|<|= symbols that highlight the conflict
6. Then add, commit and push